# Start with viewer HTML/JavaScript

Tags: authorization, autodesk-forge

I followed this steps:

1. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-2-legged-authentication-model-translation
   and uploaded and checked file, everything is OK.
2. Now I need to view file in viewer so I try this example:
   http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui
3. when I execute index.html, I see this error in debugger:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)

How to authorize using examples from http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui

Comment: Welcome to Stack, please provide some code in order to resolve the issue

Comment: I'm using code from here: http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui with other words, I downloaded 
    Index.html
    Main.css
    ForgeTree.js
    ForgeViewer.js
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Learn Forge tutorial code includes all you need to authorize/upload/translate/view files, but you need all steps to get your app running. The tutorial [starts here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels).

You'll see that the [UI side](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui) calls the server side [to require an access token](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/2legged/). As a learning experience, I would suggest doing all steps on the tutorial. The `cURL` tutorial is a different approach.

Or just download the ready-to-use code at [this github repo](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels).

If you just want to show a model with a token obtained by cURL, using the [Developer Portal tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/), you'll that it hard-code the token. This is just for testing, the token will expire after 30 minutes.

Regarding mouse right-click, please check [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customize-viewer-context-menu).

Comment: Thank you for your support but I do not understand what I need to do. I created 4 files from http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui and I don't know what I need to do next. 
As I understand - it is viewer tutorial but I do not understand how to use it. 
Do you have some example which I can use by just putting my credentials? Or some other links where I can see steps to view file. 
Thank you.

Comment: @FranjkovicIvan you need all other steps of the tutorial, the 4 UI files are just one part of it... I have edited my answer with the link to download the entire source code ready-to-use

Comment: thank you so much for your help but your github repo (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels) does not work (it is from August 07 2018 so maybe you posted wrong link?

Comment: on the README you'll see links for each language, which one are you using?

Comment: Thank you for additional info, I'm not using any language, just HTML and JavaScript. Now I checked PHP example and inside index.php, included is /vendor/autoload.php... where is that file? Can you please create some complete example for HTML and JavaScript only, like http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui, which include authorization part, please? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, such a sample is not possible, we need the server side to perform authentication. And is best practice to handle upload & translation on server side in order to protect your write-enabled token.

Comment: I understand you need server side to perform authentication, that's OK. I just need example of how to authenticate.. I'm using this steps to authenticate on server: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-2-legged-authentication-model-translation and to create bucket, to upload file and to check status is everything is OK. As I have confirmation that everything is OK, I need to see uploaded file in viewer.. I have Access Token like here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/ but question is - how to use it and how to see uploaded file?

Comment: Please follow the steps on the tutorial: http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels, that will give you a working sample :-)

Comment: I don't see how and where to write access token to view the file? your examples are based on .NET, PHP, NodeJS etc. I'm using HTML+JavaScript and using curl, I can get access token (4 steps are done, now I need only to view the file. I can not find that because your examples are based on specific langauges. I think this example is OK (http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/ui) but I need somewhere to put my access token?

Comment: added a paragraph on my answer, please take a look

Comment: Thank you. If I increase expireTimeSeconds value, does it mean it will be active for longer time?

Comment: that time cannot be modified, sorry

Comment: Hello, this link (from your tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/) does not exist: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.min.js

Comment: We removed three.min.js call from your example but it still does not work :( here is what I get
`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/adsk.objects%3Aos.object%3Agala_b1%2Fgala.ifc?domain=file%3A%2F%2F 400 (Bad Request)
test.html:72 onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:7`
it is more then month since I try to view simple file without success. Could you be so kind and write one working example, step by step, using cUrl to upload file and to view it, thanks.

Comment: Please, any help?

Comment: @FranjkovicIvan on the URL you pointed, the URN is not Base64 encoded, which is required.

Comment: I'm using your example from https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-application/ I just pasted error code which I see after I remove three.min.js from your example. What I wanted to tell you is that your example does not work, it give me error which I posted. So if you be so kind and help to create working example using cURL to obtain token, I will be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Augusto, can you create such example, please?

Comment: This should have a CURL example: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-2-legged-authentication-model-translation

Comment: That example is for everything else but not to view uploaded file and I need example to view file in viewer uploaded by cURL. This example: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/ does not work. Any other example, please?

Comment: Is that what you mean? https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/

Comment: I did all those steps before and now I try new viewer (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/tutorials/basic-viewer/) and it finally worked.

Comment: Yes, thank you too. Now I try to extend basic Viewer (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/tutorials/basic-viewer/) and add custom menu (on right click) - how to do that, please? Also, how to get details of clicke dobject? (I'm using IFC file and there are Volume, Area etc. - how to get them for clicked object, please?

Comment: I have edited my answer with information. For other questions, please start a new question, Stackoverflow will soon block more comments here :) And, if possible, please accept answer as solution, thanks

Comment: OK I posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989533/how-to-add-custom-menu-to-autodesk-forge-viewer
Thank you.