# How to add custom menu to Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Helo
I'm using Viewer Example form here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/tutorials/basic-viewer/
(Step 1)
and now I need:

```
1. add custom menu on right click
2. get info's for clicked object, like Area, Volume, Length (if 3D) or length if 2D.
```

How to do that, please?

I try to copy whole "class MyContextMenu extends ... " code from
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/customize-viewer-context-menu
but it does not worked.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details on why the customized context menu isn't working? Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: There is no any error.  
It is just not displayed when I right-click.
Also, do you know how to get details about clicked object, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of adding custom menu items to the context menu: http://jsfiddle.net/s47vy5u3/2. You'll just need to include your Forge app's access token and some viewable URN. The menu customization code itself looks like this:

```
function customizeMenu() {
    const viewer = NOP_VIEWER;
    viewer.registerContextMenuCallback('MyCustomMenuItems', function(menu, status) {
    menu.push({
      title: 'My custom menu item',
      target: () => {
        // Add your menu item's code here
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Do you also know answer on second part of question - how to get info about clicked object, like Area, Length, Volume? Thank you again.

Comment: When you select a part of your model by clicking on it, you can call `viewer.getSelection()` which returns an array of IDs of selected objects. With an ID, you can then call `viewer.getProperties(id, callback)` which will call the callback function with all kind of properties available for this object.

Comment: Can you be so kind and update your example http://jsfiddle.net/s47vy5u3/2 with that code, please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here's an updated version of the snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/s47vy5u3/3. After clicking on the custom context menu item, it will take the first object that's been selected and output its properties to the console.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it works but there is still one problem (for me). If you take a look at this image(https://imgur.com/a/OJ5sV6N) you will see what I get now (based on your example) in console, but what I need is this: https://imgur.com/71Rm0Y4
With other words, now I see only "Item" and "Material" properties and there are more properties, like "Quantities", "Pset_WallCommon" and others. How to get them, please?

Comment: In that case you'll need to traverse the _instance tree_ and find the IDs of the parent you're interested in. There are many articles on how the _instance tree_ works, for example, https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-all-dbid-without-enumerating-model-hierarchy.

Comment: Btw. this goes quite beyond the scope of the original question, so feel free to start a new question if you need more help, and consider flagging this answer as helpful if it did answer the original question.